# numpy.array.tolist() converts numpy.datetime64 to int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, types

I have an array of datetimes that I need to convert to a list of datetimes. My array looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array(['2017-06-28T22:47:51.213500000', '2017-06-28T22:48:37.570900000',
                     '2017-06-28T22:49:46.736800000', '2017-06-28T22:50:41.866800000',
                     '2017-06-28T22:51:17.024100000', '2017-06-28T22:51:24.038300000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

my_list = my_array.tolist()
```

I need a list of datetime values, but when I do `my_array.tolist()`, I get a list of numerical time stamps:

```
[1498690071213500000,
 1498690117570900000,
 1498690186736800000,
 1498690241866800000,
 1498690277024100000,
 1498690284038300000]
```

My question is **how do I preserve the datetime format when going from an array to a list**, or **how do I convert the list of time stamps to a list datetime values**?

Comment: *"I need a list of datetime values..."*  Do you want instances of `numpy.datetime64` (as in @ErickShepherd's answer), or do you want instances of [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly casting the `numpy.ndarray` as a native Python `list` will preserve the contents as `numpy.datetime64` objects:

```
>>> list(my_array)
[numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:47:51.213500000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:48:37.570900000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:49:46.736800000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:50:41.866800000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:51:17.024100000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:51:24.038300000')]
```

However, if you wanted to go back from an integer timestamp to a `numpy.datetime64` object, the number given here by `numpy.ndarray.tolist` is given in nanosecond format, so you could also use a list comprehension like the following:

```
>>> [np.datetime64(x, "ns") for x in my_list]
[numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:47:51.213500000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:48:37.570900000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:49:46.736800000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:50:41.866800000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:51:17.024100000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-06-28T22:51:24.038300000')]
```

And if you want the final result as a Python `datetime.datetime` object instead of a `numpy.datetime64` object, [you can use a method like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753985/8685423) (adjusted as needed for locality):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> list(map(datetime.utcfromtimestamp, my_array.astype(np.uint64) / 1e9))
[datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 47, 51, 213500),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 48, 37, 570900),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 49, 46, 736800),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 50, 41, 866800),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 51, 17, 24100),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 51, 24, 38300)]
```

**Edit:** [Warren Weckesser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72484984/8685423) provides a more straightforward approach to go from a `numpy.datetime64[ns]` array to a list of Python `datetime.datetime` objects than is described here.

Answer (score 8):

NumPy can't convert instances of `'datetime64[ns]'` to Python `datetime.datetime` instances, because `datetime` instances do not support nanosecond resolution.

If you cast the array to `'datetime64[us]'`, so the timestamps have only microsecond resolution, then the `.tolist()` method will give you `datetime.datetime` instances:

```
In [25]: my_array
Out[25]: 
array(['2017-06-28T22:47:51.213500000', '2017-06-28T22:48:37.570900000',
       '2017-06-28T22:49:46.736800000', '2017-06-28T22:50:41.866800000',
       '2017-06-28T22:51:17.024100000', '2017-06-28T22:51:24.038300000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')

In [26]: my_array.astype('datetime64[us]').tolist()
Out[26]: 
[datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 47, 51, 213500),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 48, 37, 570900),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 49, 46, 736800),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 50, 41, 866800),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 51, 17, 24100),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 22, 51, 24, 38300)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
# convert to string type first
my_list = my_array.astype(str).tolist()
my_list
# ['2017-06-28T22:47:51.213500000', '2017-06-28T22:48:37.570900000', '2017-06-28T22:49:46.736800000', '2017-06-28T22:50:41.866800000', '2017-06-28T22:51:17.024100000', '2017-06-28T22:51:24.038300000']
```

The other answers provide a more straightforward ways but for completeness, you can call `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` in a loop

```py
from datetime import datetime
[datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in my_array.astype(object)/1e9]

#[datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 15, 47, 51, 213500),
# datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 15, 48, 37, 570900),
# datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 15, 49, 46, 736800),
# datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 15, 50, 41, 866800),
# datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 15, 51, 17, 24100),
# datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 15, 51, 24, 38300)]
```